# Como fazer uma conta em sequencia SQL

Tags: sql, query, oracle, sqldeveloper

Como pode ser implementado uma funcionalidade que subtraia  automáticamente  um valor que possui um limite partir dos valores de compra,
sendo que esse limite inicial é 1000 e cada compra feita é subtraída do limite atual, seguindo o sistema financeiro da empresa?

*Por exemplo*, a primeira compra  de 100, o limite seria atualizado para 900 e se a segunda compra for de 200, o limite seria atualizado para 700.

Estou usando o banco de dados Oracle SQL Developer.

Não posso estar criando tabelas ou colunas, gostaria de realizar apenas na consulta, tenho chegado perto do resultado com a função LAG()

Imagem com resultado próximo, porém ainda incorreto.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBp4s.png

query atual:

```
SELECT
    QTDCOMPRAS,
    IDVENDA,
    CPF,
    DATA,
    TOTALCOMPRA,
    SEXO AS GENERO,
    LIMITCREDITO,
    FORMAPAGAMENTO,
    CASE 
        WHEN (FORMAPAGAMENTO = 'SISTEMA_FINANCEIRO') THEN LAG(TOTALCOMPRA,1) OVER(PARTITION BY - LIMITCREDITO ORDER BY DATA ASC)
        ELSE LIMITCREDITO
        END AS LIMITE_REDUZIDO,
    STORE
        
FROM
    CTE1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### SOLUÇÃO 1: criando uma nova coluna

Você não falou qual é o banco de dados que você está usando mas vou **supor** que é o `MySQL`. Uma forma de implementar essa funcionalidade seria adicionar uma coluna "limite_atual" na tabela de vendas, inicializando-a com o valor 1000. Em seguida, criar uma *trigger* que atualize essa coluna a cada vez que uma nova compra for inserida na tabela. A lógica da *trigger* poderia ser algo como: "subtrair o valor da compra da coluna 'limite_atual'".

A query também poderia ser modificada para incluir a coluna "limite_atual" e utilizá-la no lugar de "limite_crédito" na cláusula SELECT.

Código do *trigger*:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_credit_limit
AFTER INSERT ON sales
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE sales SET credit_limit = credit_limit - NEW.total_purchase WHERE id = NEW.id;
END;
```

E agora a query:

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CPF ORDER BY DATA ASC) AS QTDCOMPRAS,
    IDVENDA,
    CPF,
    DATA,
    TOTALCOMPRA,
    SEXO,
    limite_atual,
    TOTALCOMPRA - DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY limite_atual ORDER BY DATA ASC) AS LIMITE_REDUZIDO,
    FORMAPAGAMENTO,
    STORE
FROM
    CTE
```

### SOLUÇÃO 2: sem criar uma nova coluna

Nesse caso é possível usar uma subquery ou uma função de agregação na query para calcular o limite atual com base nas compras já realizadas.

Por exemplo, você poderia utilizar uma subquery para calcular o total de compras realizadas para cada CPF e subtrair esse valor do limite inicial de 1000:

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CPF ORDER BY DATA ASC) AS QTDCOMPRAS,
    IDVENDA,
    CPF,
    DATA,
    TOTALCOMPRA,
    SEXO,
    (1000 - (SELECT SUM(TOTALCOMPRA) FROM CTE WHERE CPF = outer_cte.CPF)) AS LIMITE_ATUAL,
    FORMAPAGAMENTO,
    STORE
FROM
    CTE as outer_cte
```

ou então utilizando a função de agregação SUM() para calcular o total de compras realizadas e subtrair esse valor do limite inicial:

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CPF ORDER BY DATA ASC) AS QTDCOMPRAS,
    IDVENDA,
    CPF,
    DATA,
    TOTALCOMPRA,
    SEXO,
    (1000 - SUM(TOTALCOMPRA) OVER (PARTITION BY CPF)) AS LIMITE_ATUAL,
    FORMAPAGAMENTO,
    STORE
FROM
    CTE
```

Comment: Fiz uma edição com bem mais detalhes, espero que possa me responder novamente.